# Chartjs - Add backgroundColor for labels radar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[>>> Radar chart labels with background color](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qk2jej54svmc5rg/others%20%3E%20radar%20%7C%20Chart.js%20sample%202017-12-27%2015-27-06.png?dl=0)

Hi there, I just want to ask for an option to add the background color (a rounded rect with bg color) for labels (individually) in Chartjs. Is there any callback that I can apply for changing this, any help is appreciated with best regards!

This is the current code:

```
let chart = new Chart('chart-0', {
  type: 'radar',
  data: radarChartData,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Radar Chart | Chart.js',
      fontSize: 16
    },
    scale: {
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      },
      pointLabels: {
        fontSize: 14, // fontSize is ok
        fontColor: presets.blue, // fontColor is accessible
        backgroundColor: presets.yellow //This is not working for sure!
      }
    },
    animation: {
        animateScale: true,
        animateRotate: true
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please add some code you've already tried.

Comment: @RonnieOosting Yes! I have updated the code for your reference...

Answer (score 1):

You can do using backgroundColor.

```
data: {
    labels: chart_label,
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: chart_data,
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
```

Comment: I think this is for datasets, labels' background color is what I need instead. Thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs the answer, I did posted in in chartjs and Tim has done it so well: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5085

Rgrds,